# Should I simplify the compound function $f/g$ before calculating the domain?

Tags: polynomials

Consider the functions $f(x)=x^2-14x+49$ and $g(x)=x-7$ and $f(x)/g(x)=(x^2-14x+49)/(x-7)$, notice how $f$ is $g^2$ because you can factor $x^2-14x+49=(x-7)^2$ so $f/g = (x-7)^2/(x-7) = (x-7)$. So since $f/g = x-7$ which is just a line the domain should just be $(-\infty,\infty)$ right? But here is what I just noticed: If you consider the function at some earlier point (stop before the simplification so we are considering $f/g = (x^2-14x+49)/(x-7)$ ) you get a different domain. Namely the real numbers minus the singularity at $x=7$. Why would carrying out the simplification alter the domain?

Comment: $\frac{x}{x} = 1$ only if $x$ is non-zero by definition of division.

Comment: f(x)/g(x) does *not* equal x -7.  f(x)/g(x) = x -7 for all a in R except 7.  To say a function in terms of a variable is equal to another function in terms of the same variable means that the are equal at and for the same points.  f(7)/g(7) is undefined, while 7 - 7 = 0.  So the two expressions are *not* equal.  Instead we say they are "equal for all x not equal to 7".  Which is slightly different.  They are equal at every other point but not at 7.  If they are inequal or inconsistently defined at any point, even just one point, the are different expressions.

Comment: that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that simplifying the expression does indeed change the domain. Why this is is actually a really important subtle point.

In algebra, we learn how to manipulate expressions pretty willy-nilly. Unfortunately, we're not always taught to be as careful as we should! This is a perfect case; when you simplify the expression, you would *have* to say 
$$f(x)=x-7\quad x\neq 0$$

Without the caveat, the equality is simply wrong. This is true whether you're thinking about functions, or any expression, or anything with symbols in a line!

More generally, this is about *non-invertible* operations. When you apply a non-invertible operation, you make some extra assumption about the world that makes the problem subtly easier. In this case, if you assume $x\neq0$, the world becomes easier. But generally, $f(x)=\frac{x^2-14x+49}{x-7}$ does *not* necessarily imply $f(x)=x-7$.

These and similar problems are exactly the reason we mathematicians always need to be thinking about domains and codomains - where is this defined???

Comment: Ok thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you simplify the function or not, the function:

$$f(x) = \frac{(x-7)^2}{x-7}$$

Doesn't have the same domain as:

$$f(x) = x-7$$

The first one has a hole at $x = 7$, meaning it is undefined at the point $(7, 0)$.

Note that if we substitute $x=7$ in the first function we get:

$$f(x) = \frac{0}{0}$$

Which is an indeterminate form and therefore undefined.

Comment: that's what I said though

Comment: No, it isn't.  x-7 has R as its domain.  But 7 is *not* in the domain of f(x)/g(x) so they do not have the same domain.